# How to get error messages from ruby threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm having a problem right now where I can't see where my child threads are spitting out error messages which is making it difficult to debug.

eg:

```
Thread.new{
    a = 1/0
}
```

Is there any way to have all thread errors print out at stderr?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the Thread class' `abort_on_exception` flag to true.

Alternately, wrap the thread body in a throw/catch block and dump the exception in the catch.

Answer (score 9):

Set `$DEBUG` to true (you can do this from the command line with `-d`), and you'll get

```
ruby -d bad_thread.rb 
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1113 - no such file to load -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:34 - no such file to load -- Win32API
Exception `ZeroDivisionError' at bad_thread.rb:2 - divided by 0
bad_thread.rb:2:in `/': divided by 0 (ZeroDivisionError)
    from bad_thread.rb:2
    from bad_thread.rb:1:in `initialize'
    from bad_thread.rb:1:in `new'
    from bad_thread.rb:1
```

Comment: Thank you! This has just increased my debugging speed on a troublesome DRb server by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 6):

This should catch any errors you don't explicitly handle and print them to STDOUT.

```
require 'pp'

Thread.new {
  begin
    a = 1/0
  rescue
    pp $!
  end
}
```

result: `#<ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0>`