# How to capture an exception from another thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception

How can I capture an exception from another thread?

- I want to do this for some particular thread, and not for other threads, so I cannot turn on `abort_on_exception` to `true`.
- I want to do something in the main thread with the exception, so I cannot simply do `puts`, `pp`, etc. with the exception within the thread that raised in exception.

I found an answer in [How to get error messages from ruby threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524019) that suggests using `catch`, and I think that is the way I want to go, but I cannot not fully figure out how to do it. Or is there a better way? I also found an answer suggesting to use `Queue` class, but have concern that it may be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on `abort_on_exception` then you won't have a chance to catch it. You can, however, leave that off and simply catch it when you do the `join` operation on your thread.

```
thread = Thread.new do
  raise "Uh oh"
end

begin
  thread.join
rescue => e
  puts "Caught exception: #{e}"
end
```

The alternative is to make the thread catch its own exception and save it somewhere you can fetch it from later. For instance:

```
exceptions = { }

Thread.new do
  begin
    raise "Uh oh"
  rescue => e
    exceptions[Thread.current] = e
  end
end

sleep(1)

puts exceptions.inspect
# => {#<Thread:0x007f9832889920 dead>=>#<RuntimeError: Uh oh>}
```

Comment: One thing to note is, when you `join` thread, the main thread will wait for joined thread to finish. To get most out of the concurrency stick to second approach.